# can't acces to body propietie in post request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created an API in laravel for my project, but I can't access to access body values in the post request.
in web.php I defined this route:

```
Route::post('/comanda', 'ItemsController@order');
```

in ItemsController I defined order method like this :

```
public function order(Request $request) {
        $produse = json_decode($request->input('produse'));
        $comanda = new Comenzi;
        $success = false;
        foreach($produse as $produs) {
            $comanda->produs_id = $produs->id;
            if($comanda->save()) {
                $success = true;
            }
        }
        return json_encode(array(
            'success' => $success
        ));
    }
```

in postman i sent body object like this:

```
{
    "produse":[ {
        "id": 1,
        "denumire": "telefon",
        "pret": 500,
        "pozaUrl": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517439270744-8d9287c2f8f8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=992&q=80",
        "categorie": "electronice",
        "created_at": "2020-03-11T12:52:20.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-11T12:52:20.000000Z"
    }]
}
```

when i run `echo $produse` it didn't show nothing.
how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

No need to decode input parameter. It's already json decoded.

Change the code as follows.

```
$produse = $request->input('produse');
```

And one more thing, `echo $produse` won't work because it's an array. use `print_r` to see the data of an array.

Comment: ok but it shows s me this error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mo-api/app/Http/Controllers/ItemsController.php on line 20
`

Comment: @CosminCiolacu You have to set the HTTP Header `Content-Type:application/json` while posting json data.

Comment: @CosminCiolacu Can you attach the postman screenshot to your question.